# Why doesn't my dynamic table have filtering?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to use a drop down menu to display different tables that can be filtered using tablefilter.js (found on http://tablefilter.free.fr/).  The tables show up, but they do not have filtering capabilities.

Here is the code I have for test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="TableFilter/tablefilter.js">    </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sel_change(choice){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("spn_table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    var table1Filters = {  
     col_0: "select",  
     col_1: "select",
     alternate_rows: true,
    }  
    var tf01 = setFilterGrid(choice,table1Filters);
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","testphp.php?choice="+choice,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="frm_summaries">
  <select id = "styleselect" name = "sel_choice" onchange = "sel_change(this[selectedIndex].text);">
   <option>hockey</option>
   <option>baseball</option>
   <option>basketball</option>
  </select>
 </form>
 <p>
 <span id="spn_table"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code I have for testphp.php:

```
<?php
$choice=$_GET["choice"];
if ($choice == "hockey"){
  echo "<table class=\"mytable TF\" id="; echo $choice; echo ">";
   echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>first name</th>";
    echo "<th>last name</th>";
   echo "</tr></thead>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Sidney</td>";
    echo "<td>Crosby</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Wayne</td>";
    echo "<td>Gretzky</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Mario</td>";
    echo "<td>Lemieux</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
} else if ($choice == "baseball"){
  echo "<table class=\"mytable TF\" id="; echo $choice; echo ">";
   echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>first name</th>";
    echo "<th>last name</th>";
   echo "</tr></thead>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Babe</td>";
    echo "<td>Ruth</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Lou</td>";
    echo "<td>Gehrig</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Mickey</td>";
    echo "<td>Mantle</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
} else if ($choice == "basketball"){
  echo "<table class=\"mytable TF\" id="; echo $choice; echo ">";
   echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>first name</th>";
    echo "<th>last name</th>";
   echo "</tr></thead>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Michael</td>";
    echo "<td>Jordan</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Larry</td>";
    echo "<td>Bird</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Wilt</td>";
    echo "<td>Chamberlain</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Please tell me what I am missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely arising from the fact that these tables are dynamically added to the page. The tablefilter.js is looking through your existing html that is part of the original file. I recommend just moving the testphp.php options into 3 different divs that are hidden. This way, the options are already part of the html. Then, when one is selected in your drop down choices, just simply change the style of the selected div to show. This will avoid you having to rewrite parts of tablefilter.js.

P.S. you don't need so many echo's in your php. One will do for each table. haha.

Comment: I had thought about doing it the way you mentioned (with divs that are hidden), but I was hoping not to load all three tables at once, as they will be bigger than the example I showed.  Thanks for the tip on echo's.

Comment: Well, in that case, call the php tables with ajax. Then, use jQuery to sort the tables. It'll be little bit of jquery but, it'll work.